# how to prevent infinite while loop in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am creating a program that plays the game pig dice. It should do the following:
1. Select whether the user or the computer plays the first turn.
2. If computer starts first, computer plays one turn
3. Repeat as long as computer score is less than 100:
a. User plays one turn.
b. If user’s score reaches 100, exit loop
c. Computer plays one turn.
4. Print results.
My problem is that when I run the program, there is an infinite loop, and I am not sure where it is running into this problem. Could anyone point out where the problem is occurring and possibly make suggestions as to how to prevent this? Pointing out any other errors is also appreciated as I am new to python.

```
from random import randint


def print_scores(uscore, cscore):
    uscore = 0
    cscore = 0


    print(uscore, cscore)


def roll_two_dice():
    roll1 = randint(1, 6)
    roll2 = randint(1, 6)

    if roll1 or roll2 == 1:
        return 0


    elif roll1 and roll2 == 1:
        return 25
    else:
        return roll1 + roll2


def computerTurn(score):


    turn_score = 0
    while score + turn_score < 100 and turn_score < 20:
        roll = roll_two_dice()
        if roll == 0:
            return 0
        score = roll + turn_score
    return turn_score


def userTurn(score):
    turn_score = 0
    while score + turn_score < 100 or user == hold:
        roll = roll_two_dice()
        if roll == 0:
            return 0
        score = roll + turn_score
    return turn_score


def final_result(uscore, cscore):
    uscore = 0
    cscore = 0
    print('Final results:{}'.format(uscore, cscore))
    if uscore >= 100:
        print('You win')
    else:
        print('Computer wins')


def main():
    c_score = 0
    u_score = 0
    if randint(0, 1) == 0:
        print('Computer starts')
        c_turn = computerTurn(c_score) + c_score
    while c_score < 100:
        print('Current scores')
        print_scores(u_score, c_score)
        u_turn = userTurn(u_score) + u_score
        if u_score >= 100:
            exit
        c_turn = computerTurn(c_score)
        print(c_turn)
        c_score = c_score + c_turn
    final_result(u_score, c_score)


main()
```

[codepart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHnBn.jpg)

[codepart2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVQPL.jpg)

Comment: Don't think it's directly related to your problem, but: `if roll1 or roll2 == 1:` does not mean "if either of roll1 or roll2 are equal to 1", it means "if roll1 is anything other than zero, or if roll2 equals 1". The `elif` following that line has a similar problem.

Comment: On second thought, maybe it _is_ directly related to your problem, since it makes `roll_two_dice` always return zero, which makes it so nobody's score ever goes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code as I have gone through your code extensively.

1. In the following code segment

   def roll_two_dice():
       roll1 = randint(1, 6)
       roll2 = randint(1, 6)

   ```
   if roll1 or roll2 == 1:
       return 0


   elif roll1 and roll2 == 1:
       return 25
   else:
       return roll1 + roll2
   ```

   both the cases should contain ,

roll1 == 1

As the condition that you have written will not check that either roll1 =1 or roll2 =1.Actually it checks roll2 = 1 and roll1 anything other than 1. That could might result in making an infinite loop.

2. Secondly in the following 2 functions :-

   computerTurn(score)

   and

   userTurn(Score)

You are not updating the value of the turn_score and returning that value that results to make the matter worse and the values c_score always renders to 0 and code will fall in infinite loop.

3. Also in function

   def final_result(uscore, cscore):

You should not make the values of uscore and cscore = 0 as the condition for uscore >= 100 will never come

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
if u_score >= 100:
    exit
```

"exit" isn't the keyword to leave a loop, it's "break". If you actually want the program to terminate, you need to call the method with `exit()`.